# Is there a way to force a tooltip to show?

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, tooltip

I have a method that validates a field. If it cannot be validated the field gets cleared and marked red.

I also would like a ToolTip to pop up over the box with a message for the user that the value is invalid. Is there a way to do this and maybe control how long the ToolTip shows? How can I make it pop up on it's own and not on mouse hover?

Comment: WinForms? WPF? Something else?

Comment: where do u want the pop up to come? Tooltips appear on hover...if u want it to always be present its likely u want another element to appear on screen. Cause u will also have to set its position on screen.

Comment: i just want it to pop in its normal location, right next to the control. pop up and show for a couple seconds

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> "If the field cannot be validated, i have it clearing the box and marking it red. I would also like it to pop up a tooltip over the box saying that the value is invalid."

From the description of the behavior that you want, it sounds like you would be best served by the [`ErrorProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0d996e0.aspx) component rather than a tooltip. The `ErrorProvider` component will automatically place an icon you specify next to the control that failed validation and display a tooltip to the user describing the validation error and/or the steps they need to take to correct it:

[image: ErrorProvider component in action]

There is a sample available on [C# Corner](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/tanmayit08/2950/Default.aspx), but it's very simple to implement. Simply add an `ErrorProvider` component to your form (it's available by default in the toolbox), then in your validation method, write the following code:

```
private void ValidateName()
{
 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(NameTextBox.Text))
    {
            //Validation failed, so set an appropriate error message
            errorProvider.SetError(NameTextBox, "You must enter your name");
    }
    else
    {
            //Clear previous error message
            errorProvider.SetError(NameTextBox, string.Empty);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:
Basically,

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ToolTip toolTip1 = new ToolTip();
    toolTip1.Title = "Invalid entry"; // Title to display.
    toolTip1.Show("Please enter a number.", textBox1); // Message of the toolTip and to what control to appear.
}
```

But there are 5 other overloads for ToolTip. You can see it **[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.show%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)**.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.settooltip%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) you have an example. Play with properties of the tooltip and the tooltip will show as you want.

You have the [Show](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.show%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) method on the tooltip.

Note: .net 2.0 version

Comment: ok so i got it to set the properties. but im missing how to get it to show automatically rather than only on mouse hover

Answer (score 0):

Is this a winforms app...if so [Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168550/how-can-i-display-a-tooltip-over-a-button-using-winforms)

If its a ASP.NET web app...you can add a field called [tooltip](http://www.w3schools.com/ASPNET/prop_webcontrol_standard_tooltip.asp)