# creating a tip balloon over a control on hover?

Tags: vb.net

I simply want when someone hovers his mouse over a checkbox a "tip balloon" to appear describing what the control does?

How can this be done?

Using VB.NET with Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: @p.campbell: rats, I always forget to ask that.

Comment: @Musi: I suspect it's WinForms, but you never know, I guess. I always hate to be wrong on SO! ;)

Comment: @p.campbell: with WinForms v. WPF, you can't be wrong - only irrelevant.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Drag a `ToolTip` control from the toolbox on the left onto your form (the designer will then put it below your form, since it's not meant to be visible normally).  By default it will be named "tooltip1".

Then select your checkbox and go over to its properties window.  You should see a property labeled "Tooltip on tooltip1" - set this to whatever you want.  When you run the app and hold the mouse over your checkbox, you should see the tooltip text.

Comment: if i want multiple tool tips for multiple controls should i use a different ToolTip control??

Comment: @John: no, you only need one ToolTip on your form (each control will have a different "Tooltip on tooltip1" property).

Comment: Thank you very much! i apreciate it greatly!

Comment: @John: FWIW, in the old (pre-.NET) days of Visual Basic, `ToolTipText` was just a property of a control, which had the immense disadvantage of being simple and easy.

Comment: @MusiGenesis: what??? how is simple and easy a bad thing? 
Now it is still easy, you just have to know about it and you can't just guess where it is...

Comment: @John: sarcasm. I'm actually a big fan of simplicity.

Comment: @MusiGenesis simplicity fan here also! for every `ToolTip` a property is dynamically added on each control like `Tooltip on tooltipXXX`... can i puke NOW or should i wait for more?

Comment: @Sharky: always puke now if you can.

Answer (score 1):

For WinForms, see [Display a tooltip over a button using Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168550/how-can-i-display-a-tooltip-over-a-button-using-winforms), or briefly stated...

1. Drag in a ToolTip.
2. this.toolTip1.SetToolTip(this.targetControl, "My Tool Tip")

For WPF:

```
 <Button>Click Me
            <Button.ToolTip>
                <ToolTip>Blob of text.
                </ToolTip>
            </Button.ToolTip>
        </Button>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
tooltip1.show("Your text", then your control)
```