# Can I hover a graphics object in vb .net (winforms)?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I want to show a tooltip every time I hover a graphics object. I used a bitmap to draw a graphics object in the picture box.

Comment: I tried to make shapes(polygon) but now I will used the MouseHover event and put tooltip everytime I hover to those graphics objects.

Comment: @Kevs did you try my answer

Comment: @Kevs if my answer works will you click the tick that appears beside the answer when you hover beside it. it should turn green. thanks

Comment: clarified a few points and corrected usage of 'a'

Answer (score 0):

Picturebox does not have a tooltip feature in visual studio, not that i know of anyway. Here is a work around.

```
imports System.Drawing    

Dim varname as new ToolTip()
varname.SetToolTip(PictureBox1, "Tooltip data here")
```

If you have added the box with WithEvents then use the following code

```
Private tool As ToolTip = New ToolTip()

Sub OnPictureMouseHover(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseHover
    tool.Show("Tooltip", Me)
End Sub

Sub OnPictureMouseLeave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseLeave
    tool.Hide()
End Sub
```

Comment: otherwise there is a solution using a form control here http://stackoverflow.com/a/5545317/1675954

Comment: What do you mean by image1? How can I used the Mouse_Hover event?

Comment: a tooltip comes up by default on mouse hover!

Comment: its the name of the picturebox

Comment: I draw shapes using graphics and put it on a bitmap and overlay it to the picture box. After that, I want to use the mouse_hover event(PictureBox1) to show tooltip every time I hover in an graphics objects.