# c# How can I show a message when the cursor waiting on a label?

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip

This is my question as a beginner programmer. I have a C# form application. I want to show a message while mouse cursor is waiting on a label, a textbox or a button. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use MouseHover event

Comment: have a look at the Mouse events of the controls

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary " its good question" - actually not so much. It doesn't show much effort and an answer that would completely explain how to do it would be rather long. (Did not DV myself) S.Abbak: There is a little manual on writing Questions on SO: [ask].

Comment: What have you tried so far? The functionality you're looking for is called "ToolTip", you can use that keyword to find more on the subject. Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168550/display-a-tooltip-over-a-button-using-windows-forms

Answer (score 2):

You can either use mouse events or register a ToolTip for the object like this:

```
 ToolTip toolTip1 = new ToolTip();

 // Set up the delays for the ToolTip.
 toolTip1.AutoPopDelay = 5000;
 toolTip1.InitialDelay = 1000;
 toolTip1.ReshowDelay = 500;

 // Set up the ToolTip text for the Button.
 toolTip1.SetToolTip(this.button1, "Hey it works!");
```

Comment: "First of all I don't think this should be downvoted since he is a beginner, at least say why you downvoted." - That part should be a comment.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked :)