# How to set tooltip property of a form control in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Just installed VS2017.
..making a new VB.NET GUI project.
Added some controls.
..want to add a popup tooltip, but in properties of controls, no ToolTip

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/168550/3775798) and see if that gets you started. You need to create a separate ToolTip component in your Form first before the property you're looking for will appear. (I am assuming you are using Windows Forms for your GUI framework.)

Answer (score 0):

Simply go to the properties of the particular control(s), scroll to the **Tooltip on tooltipname** you added and type what you want to appear in the tooltip in the space next to it.

Say, you added a tooltip to the "**NameTextBox**", and gave the name "**NameToolTip**" to it.
Go to the "**NameTextBox**" properties;
Scroll to the property, "**Tooltip on NameToolTip**" and simply type the tip you want to be displayed.