# How to add tooltip on everything? vb.net

Tags: vb.net, tooltip

I have a program with a lot of buttons, and need to put a tooltip on every single button. Every buttton has its own text describing what it does. I would put a tooltip on every button, and add the text to the tooltip, but I guess that its not a very efficient way to do it. What would be the best way to put a tooltip on every item I wish with its own text?

thanks

Comment: Some suggestions can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168550/display-a-tooltip-over-a-button-using-windows-forms).

Comment: You only need **ONE** ToolTip control on your Form.  A "ToolTip on ToolTip1" entry will be added to the existing controls property grid where you can set the tip.  This can also be done programmatically.

Comment: Please include what have you done so far? (Code)

Comment: @Idle_Mind thanks, figured it out.. but how do I have to handle this on a MultiLanguage program?