# Add tool tip/hint text to Microsoft form

Tags: microsoft-forms

is there a way to add tooltip/ hint text to a question in Microsoft form? Tried searching the web but haven't been able to find anything. Thanks.

Comment: Does this help?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168550/display-a-tooltip-over-a-button-using-windows-forms or google for `add tooltip to microsoft forms`

Comment: its not windows forms I am talking about but office 365/ microsoft form. thanks anyways.